# Таблицы создаются, но данные не сохраняются в бд

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

Приветствую! При нажатии на кнопки "создать товар" и "создать заказ" не добавляются данные в бд, но таблицы при запуске создаются.

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="primary">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/dataDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

data-DS.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/dataDS" pool-name="PostgreSQLPool">
    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/itsfortest</connection-url>
    <driver>postgresql-42.2.1.jar</driver>
    <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
    <pool>
        <max-pool-size>30</max-pool-size>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>admin</user-name>
        <password></password>
    </security>
</datasource>
</datasources>
```

Entities

```
@Entity
public class GoodsEntity {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private int price;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "goodsEntity")
    private List<GoodsInOrderEntity> goodsInOrderEntity;

    public List<GoodsInOrderEntity> getGoodsInOrderEntity() {
        return goodsInOrderEntity;
    }

    public void setGoodsInOrderEntity(List<GoodsInOrderEntity> goodsInOrderEntity) {
        this.goodsInOrderEntity = goodsInOrderEntity;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}


@Entity
public class GoodsInOrderEntity {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private GoodsEntity goodsEntity;

    @ManyToOne
    private OrderEntity orderEntity;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public GoodsEntity getGoodsEntity() {
        return goodsEntity;
    }

    public void setGoodsEntity(GoodsEntity goodsEntity) {
        this.goodsEntity = goodsEntity;
    }

    public OrderEntity getOrderEntity() {
        return orderEntity;
    }

    public void setOrderEntity(OrderEntity orderEntity) {
        this.orderEntity = orderEntity;
    }
}

    @Entity
public class OrderEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private int summaryPrice;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "orderEntity")
    private List<GoodsInOrderEntity> goodsInOrderEntity;

    public List<GoodsInOrderEntity> getGoodsInOrderEntity() {
        return goodsInOrderEntity;
    }

    public void setGoodsInOrderEntity(List<GoodsInOrderEntity> goodsInOrderEntity) {
        this.goodsInOrderEntity = goodsInOrderEntity;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getSummaryPrice() {
        return summaryPrice;
    }

    public void setSummaryPrice(int summaryPrice) {
        this.summaryPrice = summaryPrice;
    }
}
```

EJB бины

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class ManagingGoodsEJB {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "primary")
    private
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public GoodsEntity creatingThing(String name, int price){
        GoodsEntity goodsEntity = entityManager.find(GoodsEntity.class, name);

        goodsEntity.setName(name);
        goodsEntity.setPrice(price);
        entityManager.persist(goodsEntity);

        return goodsEntity;
    }


    public List<GoodsEntity> getGoods(){
        TypedQuery<GoodsEntity> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT c FROM GoodsEntity c", GoodsEntity.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class ManagingOrderEJB {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "primary")
    EntityManager entityManager;


    public OrderEntity creatingOrder(){
        OrderEntity orderEntity = new OrderEntity();

        entityManager.persist(orderEntity);
        return  orderEntity;
    }

    public boolean addingToOrder(long orderId, long thingId){

        OrderEntity orderEntity = entityManager.find(OrderEntity.class, orderId);
        GoodsEntity goodsEntity = entityManager.find(GoodsEntity.class, thingId);

        if (orderEntity==null||goodsEntity==null){
            return false;
        }

        GoodsInOrderEntity goodsInOrderEntity = new GoodsInOrderEntity();
        goodsInOrderEntity.setOrderEntity(orderEntity);
        goodsInOrderEntity.setGoodsEntity(goodsEntity);

        entityManager.persist(goodsInOrderEntity);

        return true;
    }

    public List<GoodsEntity> getGoodsInOrder(long orderId){
        OrderEntity orderEntity = entityManager.find(OrderEntity.class, orderId);

        if(orderEntity==null){
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        List <GoodsInOrderEntity> goodsInOrderEntity = orderEntity.getGoodsInOrderEntity();
        List<GoodsEntity> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (GoodsInOrderEntity goods :
                goodsInOrderEntity) {
            result.add(goods.getGoodsEntity());
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

index.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>Shop</h:head>
<h:body>

<h:form>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><h:inputText value="#{managingGoodsCDI.name}"/></td>
        <td><h:inputText value="#{managingGoodsCDI.price}"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Наименование
        </td>
        <td>
            Цена
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h:commandButton value="Создать товар" action="#{managingGoodsCDI.createThing}"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h:commandButton value="Создать заказ" action="#{managingGoodsCDI.createOrder}"/>
            </td>
    </tr>
</table>
Созданные товары
<h:dataTable value="#{managingGoodsCDI.goods}" var="Thing">
<h:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{Thing.name}"/>
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{Thing.price}"/>
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <h:commandButton value="Добавить" action="#
{managingGoodsCDI.addingToOrder(Thing)}"/>
</h:column>
</h:dataTable>
Добавленные товары

<h:dataTable value="#{managingGoodsCDI.goodsInOrder}" var="Thing">
<h:column>
<h:outputText value="#{Thing.name}"/>
</h:column>
<h:column>
<h:outputText value="#{Thing.price}"/>
</h:column>
</h:dataTable>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

persist не означает, что данные будут сохранены в базу. В вашем случае persist означает, объект будет находится в неком спике. Для сохранения нужно вызывать [flush()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#flush())

также нехватает начало и конец транзакций

```
// Start a resource transaction.
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
entityManager.persist(goodsInOrderEntity);
entityManager.flush();
// Commit the current resource transaction, writing any unflushed changes to the database.
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
entityManager.close();
```

теперь данные будут в базе